# Which version of JQuery UI does EE 2.8.x ship with?

Tags: jquery, 2.8

I checked the EE 2.x Changelog (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html) and system reqs (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html), and couldn't find anything. Then I added the `include_jquery="yes"` parameter to a `{exp:channel:form}` tag, checked browser source and found:

```
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2
```

However, when I look at JQuery UI, I get:

```
/*!
* jQuery UI @VERSION
```

What does `@VERSION` refer to? How can I find the version of JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be right - but you can check the source within the themes folder:

/themes/javascript/compressed/jquery

Comment: Thanks Jessica. I don't see anything in the .js files themselves except for @VERSION. However there is a file called version.txt in /themes/javascript/compressed/jquery which has 1.7.1 in it, so I'm assuming that's the answer.

Comment: actually not - based on plugin code, jquery UI is in range of 1.8.18-1.8.24